# Getting U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR when I call ucnv_open() for ibm-1252_P100-2000

Tags: c++, icu

I am facing issue on Linux when I run my application which uses ICU. I get U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR when I call ucnv_open() for ibm-1252_P100-2000.

I am trying to run my application from outside of it's install directory. Install directory has the application EXE and all the ICU related libs and files. So When I run the application from outside the install dir, I get the "Converter not found" error. It is unable to run unv_open() with "ibm-1252_P100-2000" as converter name. If I create a dummy directory(say AppRun) and have only 1 file in this dir - icudtxxl.dat, and I try to run my application, it runs correctly. Basically icudtxxl.dat should be present in whatever directory I run my application from. It basically only checks icudtxxl.dat in current directory.

Saw some links online which asks to set the environment variable ICU_DATA . Setting the environment variable ICU_DATA at runtime didn't help.

```
UErrorCode Status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
ICUcnv = ucnv_open("ibm-1252_P100-2000", &Status);

if(ICUcnv == NULL)
{
    string strErr("Converter not found - ");
    strErr += "ibm-1252_P100-2000";
    throw std::runtime_error( "error opening ICU converter" );
}
```

The same application works fine on Windows. I can run my application from anywhere on Windows.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] for those people familiar with ICU

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]
My application was using u_setDataDirectory() on Windows and getting the application exe path using GetModuleFileNameA();
Once it gets the application exe path, that path is set to u_setDataDirectory().

On Linux u_setDataDirectory("./") was set to current directory.

**Solution 1:** Comment u_setDataDirectory("./") and export ICU_DATA=<APP_INSTALL_DIR> and then run the application.

**Solution 2:** Get the application exe path on Linux and set the path to u_setDataDirectory(). Still exploring how to do this. I will edit the comment once I am able to get the application exe path from within.